# Images not fitting all PC sizes

Tags: html, css

First I would like to say that I had spend whole night searching for an answer right here, and because my case is different I couldn't find it. I'm making one website and homepage consists of 13 images in a horizontal way, I used `display: flex` to get them all show in a horizontal way and I used `position: relative` and `absolute` to fit them at their places.

[This is the website showing on 1920x1280 width, so the fullest width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsFhF.png)

Everything seems ok when its 1920x1280 width but once the monitor width is 1680 and smaller the page goes over the website. So the pictures stay at the same place but the page goes over the monitor width and it shows a horizontal scroll.

I want all images to fit the screen, so if the width of the monitor is 1600 or 1480 it will automatically fit it to screen and show in a same way.

I have spended more then 10 hours trying to make it but it's just I don't know how.

This is the HTML I'm using for this bubble boxes:

```
<!-- Buble Box #1 -->
<div class="bubbleboxes">

<img class="pic firstb" src="assets/img/bubbles/firstb.png">

<img class="pic secondb" src="assets/img/bubbles/secondb.png">

<img class="pic thirdb" src="assets/img/bubbles/thirdb.png">

<img class="forthb" src="assets/img/bubbles/forthb.png">

<img class="fifthb" src="assets/img/bubbles/fifthb.png">


<img class="sixstb" src="assets/img/bubbles/sixstb.png">

<img class="seventhb" src="assets/img/bubbles/seventhb.png">

<img class="eightb" src="assets/img/bubbles/eightb.png">

<img class="ninethb" src="assets/img/bubbles/ninethb.png">

</div>
<!-- End Bubble Box -->

<!-- Bubble Box #2 -->

<div class="bubbleboxes boxmargin">

<img class="tenb" src="assets/img/bubbles/tenb.png">

<img class="elevenb" src="assets/img/bubbles/elevenb.png">

<img class="twelveb" src="assets/img/bubbles/twelveb.png">

<img class="thirteenb" src="assets/img/bubbles/thirteenb.png">

</div>

<!-- End Bubble Box -->


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUzL2.png
```

And I style every image seperetly:

```
.secondb {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -12px;
}

.thirdb {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    right: 18em;
    top: 11.5em;
}

.forthb {
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    top: 88px;
    right: 19em;

}

.fifthb {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    right: 19em;
    top: 11.5em;
}

.sixstb {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    right: 37em;
    bottom: -12px;
}

.seventhb {
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    right: 38.5em;
    bottom: -2em;
}

.eightb {
    height: 270px;
    position: relative;
    right: 42em;
    bottom: 9em;
}

.ninethb {
    height: 320px;
    right: 66em;
    position: relative;
    top: 10.5em;
}

.tenb {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 3em;
    left: 2em;
}

.elevenb {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
}

.twelveb {
    left: 4em;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3em;
}

.thirteenb {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    top: 7em;
    left: 2em;
}
```

And this is a code I have used for bubbleboxes div:

```
.bubbleboxes {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

I have tried changing position of every image to ABSOLUTE, it didn't helped. I tried dividing all of these images into two seperate div's, assinging them width: 50%, so they always both take 100% of the page but it didn't helped. I tried adding div to every image and add width to all to be equal to 100% width of the page but also didn't helped.

Any tip or help will practically mean a LOT, so thanks!
Best wishes

*And I would like to say that I only need help with PC screens, I have made mobile part working and that part is working correctly. So just PC sizes > 1920.

Comment: Have you tried setting your .bubbleboxes class to position: absolute? With your current set up, your bubble images would be positioned relative to its closest parent with absolute positioning, or will default to I believe the html element.

Comment: So I should just try adding position: absolute to bubbleboxes class?

Comment: That's probably the first thing I'd try. To be honest I haven't worked much with this sort of optimization, so I'm just trying to provide some ideas that may help you in the right direction. To me that seems like it could cause issues.

Comment: Unfourtently it didn't helped, they are still moving out of the box and going wider then the screen resolution

Comment: If I don't find the solution, is it a right way to make a seperate "bubbleboxes" for each resulotion, so I set up like @media screen (min-width: 1480px) and (max-width: 1680px), and make a seperate box that will only show on this sizes. And so on, so I will create box for every size and I will just display none to other boxes for other sizes. Is this correct way?

Comment: It's hard to say what the "correct" way would be, as with most programming or web related things, there is usually more than one way to do something, and each of those ways could be correct. Usually what I would do is just try to find a way that works for my scenario, and if I need to, I can come back to it later and optimize it.

Comment: Okey mate I will still try to look on a answer and try different stuffs. Any way I can send you files on email or whereever and you can just take a look at the full code?

Answer (score 0):

All your images need to automatically scale meaning they need to use a measurement that scales with window size.

### The positioning properies of these images need to use the same measurement type as your images.

`top:;` `bottom:;` `left:;` `right:;`

Should be set to the same type of measurement as your images `width:;` and `height:;`

That way they scale with the window size. Acceptable measurements `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, `vmax`, `%`

You will probably have to tweak your CSS with this in consideration.